# Async move array of files in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a folder with some images. Some images I want to move from this to other folder. This other folder can not exsists. I know about [fs.rename](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback). But I cant image how to send to it array and dont loose asynchronous. All what I can its like:

```
let imagesArray = ['path1', 'path2' ... 'pathN']
for(img of imagesArray){
  fs.renameSync(oldPath+img, newPath+img)
}
```

How I must make it and how to make it asynchronous?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` + `Promise.all`. Return a promise in mapper and put that array in `Promise.all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using promises you will need to make `fs.rename()` to return a promise instead of a callback. You can use the util module for this (you dont need to install it with npm)

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename);
```

Now you can use `Promise.all` + `Array.map` to loop through the array using async

```
(async () => {
    await Promise.all(imagesArray.map(oldname => rename(oldname, oldname+newname));

  //Do the stuff you need to do after renaming the files
})
```